# npm install --save fs - package not being found once installed

Tags: node.js, npm, nuxt.js

When I try to run a build for my SSR Nuxt app, via `yarn run dev` I get the following **Error** message:

```
This dependency was not found:                                                                                                                                                                 
                                                                                                                                                                                               
* fs in ./node_modules/json5/lib/register.js                                                                                                                                                   
                                                                                                                                                                                               
To install it, you can run: npm install --save fs
```

Once I execute `npm install --save fs` or `yarn add fs` I still get the error

How do I get the code to build?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding the following to the Nuxt.config.js allows the build to pass:

```
extend (config, {isDev, isClient}) {
  config.node = {
    fs: 'empty'
  }
}
```